# Embed Plotly plots as SVG in RMarkdown

Tags: plotly, r-markdown, knitr

I have made a custom RMarkdown-to-HTML tool with a focus on accessibility.  In this project, I use `knitr` to convert RMarkdown to Markdown, then I convert Markdown to HTML using my own processes.

I have recently been tasked with accommodating interactive plots via Plotly with my tool. I have set the default output device to be `svglite`, however when I embed a Ploty plot as an `r` code chunk in RMarkdown, the result is a PNG raster image.

I've [since learned](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/609) this is because knitr uses a 'webshot' and will run PhantomJS and take a PNG screenshot of the plot, if I don't use knitr to convert to HTML.

Is there some way I can force knitr to output the SVG plot when converting to Markdown? I am happy to manually load any plotly.js files necessary to make the interactivity on the frontend work.

Thanks.